# Woocommerce cart page - Add "Free" to the shipping label when shipping is 0

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I use a custom shipping plugin for my WooCommerce called Table Rate. When the cart's total is more than X $, the shipping cost is set to 0.

In the cart page, when there is a shipping cost, it currently displays, for example "Postal delivery: $6,00" in the shipping method section. When the shipping is free, it displays "Postal delivery".

I would like that when the shipping is 0, it adds the text "(Free)" after "Postal delivery" in the cart and checkout page, but I can't find out where this is managed in WooCommerce. I have checked the different template files, but get stuck there. I guess it could be done with a hook in the functions.php file but I'm quite inexperienced with this.

Thank you very much.

[image: Shipping cost at 0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this

```
function custom_label( $label, $method ) {
    if ( $method->cost == 0 ) {
        $label .= "(Free)";
    }

    return $label;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'custom_label', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. From that, I can now include method selection and other things. Thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome, don't hesitate to upvote the anwser ;)